# How can one conclude upward force is related to tension in this question?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, free-body-diagram, string, statics

In preparation for the SAT Physics Subject Test, I have been doing extra practice problems. This one states:

> A garment bag hangs from a clothesline. The tension in the clothesline is $10 \,\text{N}$ on the right side of the garment bag and $10 \,\text{N}$ on the left side of the garment bag. What is the mass of the garment bag?

The book from which this problem comes has a tendency to state questions unclearly, and some of its solutions have even had typos (which is really frustrating when using the book as a practice resource).

I interpreted the problem as something like this, where $T_1$ and $T_2$ both equal $10 \,\text{N}$.

[image]

Then $$F_\text{w} = mg = T_1 \sin\theta_1 + T_2 \sin\theta_2 $$ so

$$m = \frac{T_1 \sin\theta_1 + T_2 \sin\theta_2}{g} = \frac{10 (\sin\theta_1 + \sin\theta_2 )}{g} $$

Since the SAT uses $g = 10 \,\text{m/s}^2$, this simplifies to $$m = \sin\theta_1 + \sin\theta_2$$

Also, if two strings have the same tension, then each string makes the same angle with the horizontal. Thus $\theta_1 = \theta_2,$ and it follows that

$$m = 2\sin\theta_1 .$$

Since the angles were not given, this question cannot be solved, assuming I had interpreted the question correctly.

---

For reference, this is the solution the book provided (which I can't make any sense of):

Total upward force on the garment bag is equal to the tension in the clothesline. Therefore, the magnitude of $T_{\text{total}}$ equals the garment bag's weight, $mg.$

$$T_{\text{total}} = F_\text{w}$$
$$F_\text{w} = mg$$
$$\implies m = \frac{T_{\text{total}}}{g}$$
$$\implies m = \frac{10 \,\text{N}}{10 \,\text{m/s}^2} = \boxed{1 \,\text{kg}}$$

**What confuses me about this solution is how "total upward force on the garment bag is equal to the tension in the clothesline."** I don't think the people who wrote this question would be so careless as to omit necessary information. I think if they didn't provide angles, then the question wasn't meant to be interpreted in the above manner. If anybody knows how the problem should be set up, please provide an explanation/diagram :)

Sorry for the lengthy post and thanks for reading.

Comment: I suspect they meant the rope was taut, so there was no deflected angle.

Comment: Even so, T total should be 20N (a typo perhaps)

Comment: @KyleKanos If the rope was taut, can you explain why the upward force is equal to $10 \,\text{N}$?

Comment: I disagree with bruce smitherson ... your solution to the drawing is incorrect.  If both angles are the same, then T1 = T2 = T.  In addition, the vertical component of each tension is opposite the angle that you have shown, which means that 2Tsin(theta) = mg.  Without knowing the angle, you can't get a numeric solution.

Comment: @DavidWhite Yeah, I thought at first that having the same tension doesn't necessarily imply that the angles both strings make are equal, but after working it out, I found that it does. And also, I don't know why I wrote it in terms of $\cos$. As you said, the vertical component deals with $\sin$. That was a careless mistake, so I'm not concerned about that since it's not an issue with understanding a concept. What I am concerned about is figuring out what this question is actually asking. I don't think the question was meant to be interpreted this way, otherwise the angles would've been given.

Comment: When I was studying for the PGRE a *huge* number of the problems I did were missing information, or had errors in the solutions (etc).  Don't let it discourage you!  It's an even stronger way to test your confidence in your knowledge (which, in my opinion, often contributes a lot to the final score...).

Comment: @DavidWhite I apologize, I suffer from semantic dyslexia.

Comment: @brucesmitherson, no need to apologize.  Note that in this forum, I'm hesitant to be as blunt as I was, but I couldn't think of a way to make the point AND "beat WAY around the bush".

Comment: @KyleKanos If the rope is taut, there is no lifting force. If the angle is extremely small, then the mass of the bag is extremely small. I'm really not surprised at the solution manual because publishers routinely make mistakes like this.

Comment: Since the bag has no sideways acceleration, Tcost1 = Tcost2 so t1=t2=t (the t's stand for theta) and your solution mg=2Tsint is correct and t needs to be given. Your teacher owes you an apology.

Comment: I recognize this question, and I know that book.   You would be well to find a different book; there are many errors and the answers cannot be relied upon to be correct.  Return the one you have if you can.  I will point out that I've seen errors in just about every test prep book I've seen, but the one you have has more than its share.   I've contacted the publisher, and I know for a fact that they are correcting the errors, but that doesn't help you at the moment.

Comment: Could it be that the two strings are actually not tilted? If $\theta$ is not given, I would interpret as both ropes are vertical (aligned with the weight) and they hold the bag from its corners, and not from the center. Maybe that makes sense?

Comment: Definitely consider purchasing a new practice book...

Answer (score 0):

If both the ropes are of identical material, then the fact that they have equal tension in them means, by symmetry, that they make equal angles with horizontal, call it $\theta$. Then the only equation you have is $mg=2Tsin\theta$. So unless $\theta$ is given you cannot solve the problem. If you make, say, $\theta$ small so that the hanging ropes are close to being horizontal, then a large tension $T$ will be required in the ropes so that it has appropriate component along vertical direction to balance the hanging weight.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

$$T_1/\sin \psi=T_2/\sin\psi=W_t/\sin\theta$$
$$10/\sin\psi=10/\sin\psi=W_t/\sin\theta$$
Therefore
$$10/\sin\psi=W_t/\sin\theta$$
$$W_t=F 
$$
$$\theta=360-2\psi$$
$$W_t= \frac{10\sin\theta}{\sin\psi}\tag{using lami's theorem}$$
$$ =\frac{\sin (360-2\psi)*10}{\sin\psi}$$
we know that $$\sin(A-B)=\sin A\cos B-\cos A\sin B$$
so
$$\sin (360-\psi-\psi)=-sin \psi\cos \psi-\cos\psi\sin \psi$$
$$ =-2\sin \psi\cos \psi$$
Substituting 
$$W_t=\frac{-2\sin \psi\cos \psi*10}{\sin \psi}$$
$$=-20\cos \psi$$
$$
180>\psi>90$$
Therefore wt between 20N to 0N
So 10N is justifiable

Comment: This answer might be better if you showed *how* you got the answer, rather than loosely citing a theorem.

Comment: I am still a rookie. Let me know if you think is ok

Comment: A lot of math but no answer

Comment: I don't understand why people say "Lami's theorem". It is a silly vector addition rule which has a name. @Vinay5forPrime You should probably do it the simple way, i.e: form a triangle with those three vectors and prove Lami's theorem using the sine rule.

Comment: This doesn't quite answer the question. You go from "the weight of the bag is within this range" to "let's pick an arbitrary value in that range because it agrees with the publisher" rather abruptly.